# Lovheim cube research

Tags: neuroscience, emotion, reproducible-research, model

Is there any psychology research into the validity of the [Lovheim cube of emotion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6vheim_cube_of_emotion)?

Aside from the original paper ([Lovheim, 2012](https://www.researchgate.net/profile/Hugo_Loevheim/publication/51863789_A_new_three-dimensional_model_for_emotions_and_monoamine_neurotransmitters/links/5a983e97a6fdccecff0d21dd/A-new-three-dimensional-model-for-emotions-and-monoamine-neurotransmitters.pdf)) and papers from computer sciences (the cube is being used for simulating emotions artificially), I can't find any papers backing up or expanding on its claims.

### References

Lövheim, H. (2012). A new three-dimensional model for emotions and monoamine neurotransmitters. *Medical hypotheses, 78*(2), 341-348. doi: [10.1016/j.mehy.2011.11.016](https://doi.org/10.1016/j.mehy.2011.11.016)